# Issue about loading bitmaps in CTreeCtrl

Tags: mfc

I am trying to create an image list to my control, and load additional images. The problem is that only the image that i create is used and the loaded images does not displayed. Here is my ccode:

## define IMAGE1          1

## define IMAGE2          2

## define IMAGE3          3

## define IMAGE4          4

## define IMAGE5          5

```
m_Bitmap1.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
m_Bitmap2.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP2);
m_Bitmap3.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP3);


m_ImageListTree = new CImageList;
m_ImageListTree->Create(IDB_BITMAP1, 16, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255));
m_ImageListTree->Add(&m_Bitmap2, RGB(255, 255, 255));
m_ImageListTree->Add(&m_Bitmap3, RGB(255, 255, 255));


while( ItemTree != NULL)
{
    BasicTree->SetItemImage(ItemTree, nCounter, nCounter);
    ItemTree = BasicTree->GetNextItem(ItemTree, TVGN_CHILD);
    nCounter++;
}
```

The only IDB_BITMAP1 is displayed in all tree levels. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was never in the loop, as i did not get the initial HTRREITEM before entering the loop.

Also the creation of the list in the control, intialises every new item with the bitmap you are using for the creation. You can set the image eitehr in insertion or in alter though you need to specify diferent image (fo insertion you need to define a TVINSERTSTRUCTW and set the image before inserting the whole item.